# MPMoviePlayerController becomes smaller in normal mode after exiting fullscreen

Tags: mpmovieplayercontroller, fullscreen

MPMoviePlayerController becomes smaller in normal mode after exiting fullscreen.

In 'MPMoviePlayerDidEnterFullscreenNotification' - following property is set.

Comment: This does not seem to be a question.

Comment: @mrunal still makes no sense and should be closed / removed or properly updated.

Comment: @Till: Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9078532/mpmovieplayercontroller-mpmoviescalingmode-is-not-working-with-mpmoviescalingmod

If you know anything about that then plz help